# How do I login into a Docker container running inside the specific Kubernetes pod and run an test.sh file?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I have a test.sh file which need to be run in an docker container which runs inside the Kubernetes pods via Jenkins job.

Flow:

Step1 : Run a Jenkins job which should login to a docker container running inside the pods

Step: From the container execute the test.sh script.

test.sh

echo "This is demo file"

I have a command which will give docker image running in a kubenertes pods

`kubectl get pods -n eum -o go-template --template="{{range .items}}{{range .spec.containers}}{{.image}} {{end}}{{end}}" -l app=${TIER}`

TIER = list of apps added in jenkins as choice parameter

I wanted to login to the container and run the test.sh script

Comment: Usually if you're trying to run some sort of one-off job like this, you'd create a Kubernetes Job object.  "Log into the container" is pretty much only an emergency-debugging sort of task, particularly when you typically have multiple replicas of something running in a Deployment and the constituent Pods can get deleted and recreated pretty routinely.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to  know if there is any kubectl command, which will lets us to login to the docker container running in a particular pod ?

Comment: I am able to login to the container running in a pod using ``kubectl exec -t  ${POD } /bin/bash --all-namespaces (POD is the text parameter value in my jenkins job, In which user would have entered the pod name before running the job), Now my question is : I am able to login into the container , How do I run my test.sh file on the logged container ?

Comment: @DavidMaze Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use command "kubectl exec ${POD } /bin/bash --all-namespaces -- /bin/sh test.sh" to run directly test.sh inside container, but make sure test.sh is available inside container. But in this case you need to pass pod name in this command. you can get all pods name using command

kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'

and if you want pods only for specific label then use

kubectl get pods -l  -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'

here replace  with your label selector of pods