# Run a bash script from a docker container running in kubernetes pod via Jenkins job

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I am able to login to the container running in a pod using `kubectl exec -t ${POD } /bin/bash --all-namespaces`
(POD is the text parameter value in my Jenkins job, In which user would have entered the pod name before running the job), Now my question is : I am able to login into the container , I want to my test.sh file from the logged in container ?
Flow:

Step1 : Run a Jenkins job which should login to a docker container running inside the pods

Step: From the container execute the test.sh script.

test.sh

echo "This is demo file"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I login into a Docker container running inside the specific Kubernetes pod and run an test.sh file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170646/how-do-i-login-into-a-docker-container-running-inside-the-specific-kubernetes-po)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to have two steps one step is sufficient. I believe below should get the job done

kubectl exec ${POD} /path/to/script/test.sh --all-namespaces

Below is the reference form Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/)

> kubectl exec my-pod -- ls /                         # Run command in
>   existing pod (1 container case)
>
> kubectl exec my-pod -c my-container -- ls /         # Run command in
>   existing pod (multi-container case)